# Find a variable length number inside a string from a file using awk?

Tags: bash, unix, awk, text-processing

I have many files on UNIX and wish to fetch number in that file associated with a specified pattern.

Most of the file will have a unique pattern in file like below

```
some text abc
some text abc
some text abc
(3 rows)
```

I want to print only number `3` using awk.

The number could vary from file to file, it could be 35644 or any numeric value as well.

I want to find that number using awk not sed or grep as HP unix doesn't support advanced sed/grep features.

Comment: Are the lines consecutive, or can there be different lines among them?

Comment: no need of advanced sed/grep for such simple case (basic sed would be enough). *I want to print only number* - only number OR a filename also?

Comment: The last row will be `(number rows)` text always. Lines in file may vary but there will be always a pattern like `(number rows)`.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I'm on HP unix where sed -i isn't support, hence I don't want to go for adanced grouping in sed as it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Does the following work for you?

```
sed -e 's/(\([0-9][0-9]*\) rows)/\1/;t;d'
```

If the replacemenet of the `(N rows)` by `N` was successful, `t` goes to the end of the script, otherwise, the `d` removes the line (i.e. all lines not containing the expression will be skipped).

Answer (score 0):

As you don't want (or you can't) use simple **`sed`** approaches, here's **`awk`** solution:

Sample input files:

```
$ head file[123]
==> file1 <==
some text abc
some text abc
some text abc
(3 rows)

==> file2 <==
some text abc
some text abc
some text abc
some text abc
some text abc
(5 rows)

==> file3 <==
some text abc
some text abc
(2 rows)
```

---

```
$ for f in file[123]; do awk 'END{ print FILENAME, substr($1, 2) }' "$f"; done
file1 3
file2 5
file3 2
```

---

**`sed`** solution (in my variation) would look as:

```
for f in file[123]; do echo -n "$f "; sed -n '$ s/[() ]\|rows//gp' "$f"; done
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps with this awk

```
awk -v RS='(' 'END{print $1}' infile
```